# Is it possible to pass an AxiosInstance to openapi-generator generated TypeScript classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, axios, openapi-generator

How can i pass my AxiosInstance to classes generated by openapi-generator typescript-axios template?

I tried change prototype of BaseAPI class, but it doesn't work. And there are no places where i can pass my axios instance

```
import { HotelsRestServiceApi, Configuration } from '../../generated/openapi';
import { BaseAPI } from '../../generated/openapi/base'; //Base api class generated by openapi
import { axiosClientNoAuth } from '../index'; //My AxiosInstance

const config = new Configuration({
  basePath: 'http://localhost:8080',
});

const baseApi = new BaseAPI(config, 'http://localhost:8080', axiosClientNoAuth);

const axios = new RestServiceApi(config);

axios.prototype.__proto__ = baseApi.prototype;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got solved it by modifying template:

- download baseApi.mustache file from [openapi-templates](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/typescript-axios)
- put it somewhere in your project, for example in `.openapi-generator/templates`
- modify import globalaxios to your axiosinstance:

  `import { axiosClient as globalAxios } from '../../api';`
- generate new code with cli:

  ```
    rm -rf src/generated/openapi; openapi-generator-cli generate -t .openapi-generator/templates -c openapi-generator-config.yaml
  ```

(My openapi-generator-config.yaml)

```
generatorName: typescript-axios
outputDir: src/generated/openapi
cleanupOutput: true
inputSpec: ../app/backend/target/openapi.yaml
additionalProperties:
  supportsES6: true
```